# pyinstaller on virtualenvs, No module named Import Error

Tags: python, virtualenv, pyinstaller

I am trying to create virtualenvs for my script. When I use pyinstaller without virtualenvs (just `sudo pyinstaller myscript.spec`) everything works fine. After that I activate virtualenvs and do same thing (`pyinstaller myscript.spec`) . When I try to execute this two files the standart one (first one) works but the one that I create with virtualenvs gives **ImportError: No module named 'sip'**. I did not use `sip` in my script and did not import it anywhere. I do `pip3 install sip` and compile script again but it did not change anything. What is this error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Try `sudo apt-get install python-sip` to install Ubuntu's version